# Can I change in Excel VBA combobox.list range?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any option in Excel VBA which allows me to change range of combobox? 
[See example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE1aq.png)

I would like to change number 5 in Variant/Variant(0 to 3, 0 to 5).

Combobox is filled with this code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim x As Range
    With Worksheets("Distributori")
      Set x = .Range("A2", .Range("F1000").End(xlUp))
End With

ComboBox1.RowSource = "Distributori!" & x.Address
ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
Me.ComboBox1.TextColumn = 2
```

End Sub

Comment: how is the combo box being filled?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: It is set when you load it.  You will need to load more columns.

Comment: The 5 comes from the 6 columns you set in your range (0-based). Btw use List rather than RowSource.

Comment: I have 10 columns in this sheet.

Comment: Don't stop at F then!

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try the next (adapted) code, please:

```
Dim x As Range, arrList As Variant
    With Worksheets("Distributori")
      Set x = .Range("A2", .Range("F1000").End(xlUp))
    End With
    arrList = x.Value
    With ComboBox1
        .ColumnCount = 6
        .list = arrList
        .ListIndex = 0
        .TextColumn = 2
    End With
```